# c# change FileVersionInfo for any file

Tags: c#, file-io, metadata, getfileversion

With FileVersionInfo class is very easy to read file extra information,
but is there any way i can change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no class in the .NET Framework that lets you do that easily. File version data is stored as a native resource, so it can be changed by functions like [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28VS.85%29.aspx). But it requires detailed knowledge about [the format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981%28VS.85%29.aspx) in which it's are stored in the executable.

Comment: I only want to change the file description of any file... is not a standard format?

Comment: It's standard in the way that all Win32 executables use the same format. But it's not easy to change.